# HTTP 404 Page Not Found in Web Api hosted in Windows Plesk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, plesk

I have a MVC Web Api application. It works perfectly well when I tested it using the VS 2013 Web in locally. But I now deployed it to Windows shared hosting server using Plesk control panel and I am getting a HTTP 404 error when trying to access any Web API call.

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CMEConnection" connectionString="Data Source=JIT-005;Initial Catalog=CME_Dev;User Id=sa;Password=Jit005!@#" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>      
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>  
  <system.web>`enter code here`
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/">
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error/"/>
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error/"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```